# Angular 6 - logout when only browser close not on refresh

Tags: angular

I have tried to destroy the local storage to logout when the browser close in angularjs 6. Its working fine in browser close but also when refresh the page. I just need in browser close not in refresh

Here is the code in **.ts**

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler($event) {
    localStorage.removeItem('userId');
  }
```

Comment: Is this bit of code in every component? Or do you just have one component?

Answer (score 0):

Use sessionStorage Property, it will expire once the browser closes. w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

The only way i find in angular to ensure current state is a refresh browser action is asking as this. Inject Router to your component. using sessionStorage should work normally but in chrome you should ensure application doesn't run in background in Chrome>Settings.

```
isPageRefresh(){
    return !this._router.navigated;
}
```